# How to parse a JSON key that has a hash sign # in it with the jq command?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON data:

```
{
    "module": {
        "data": {
            "deliverySummary_200648721592191#address": {
                "fields": {
                    "address": "MyAddress",
                    "consignee": "MyName",
                    "phone": "MyPhone",
                    "postCode": "",
                    "title": "Alamat Pengiriman \\r\\n"
                },
                "id": "200648721592191#address",
                "tag": "deliverySummary",
                "type": "biz"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to extract this part:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "address": "MyAddress",
        "consignee": "MyName",
        "phone": "MyPhone",
        "postCode": "",
        "title": "Alamat Pengiriman \\r\\n"
    },
    "id": "200648721592191#address",
    "tag": "deliverySummary",
    "type": "biz"
}
```

I have tried `jq '.module.data.deliverySummary_200648721592191#address'` but it just returns `null` instead of the part that I want above, how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add double-quotation-marks around the problematic property key like `'.module.data."deliverySummary_200648721592191#address"'` for your case.

See the playground result [here](https://jqplay.org/s/agSDbgpIdZ).

Comment: Thank you, is there any other special characters that I have to escape with double quotes ?

Comment: I do not have the full list indeed, but can say dashes(-) and at-sign (@) are among those. To be cautious, you can wrap every field separately like `."module"."data"."deliverySummary_200648721592191#address"` and it should also work.

Comment: One can only use the abbreviated ".foo" form for alphanumeric keys that begin with an alphabetic character, where it is understood that underscores count as alphabetic for present purposes. That is, the key must match the regex `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*`